# next_permutation time complexity in big O notation

Tags: c++, algorithm

As far as I can tell, `std::next_permutation` algorithm runs in *O(n!)* time. Can anyone explain why that is? Or if I am even right about it?

Here is the code I am running it in, trying to count the number of permutations until the given array, of size `n`, has been sorted:

```
int permutationSort(int a[], int n)
   {
      int count = 0;

      while (next_permutation(a, a + n))
      {
          count++;
      }

      return count;
   }
```

Comment: Does [this `std::next_permutation` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) help?

Comment: It has to be Omega(n!) because... it enumerates all n! permutations? The standard doesn't guarantee O(1) amortized complexity though.

Comment: It seems you confound time complexity of `next_permutation`, and time complexity of sort using `next_permutation`.

Comment: 'some programmer dude' -- kind of.... not really is it N/2 because the swap will at most swap half the elements? but...  even if it swaps half the elements there is no guarantee that it wouldn't have to swap any two elements a second time... right?

Comment: Number of permutations of a sequence of size n (without permutation) is `n!` (`n` possibilities for the first element, then `n-1` for second, then ... -> `n * (n-1) * .. * 2 * 1` -> `n!`). Here, you iterate until sequence is sorted, so you call at worst `n!` `next_permutation`.

Comment: 'jarod42' that makes sense to me.... so would you say .... worst case : n!  ------  best case: n/2 .... or is n/2 irrelevant

Comment: @kman123 Worst case is `O(n * n!)` (`n!` call to `next_permutation`), best case is `O(n)`, i.e. one call to `next_permutation` (when `a` is already at the last permutation).

Comment: @kman123 Is there a good reason to cycle through all the permutations instead of just calculating the number of permutations before the array is sorted?

Comment: @holt: can you find a set of arrays which demonstrate this worst case? Or motivate the existence of such a set?  Arrays of distinct elements certainly do not produce it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The complexity of `std::next_permutation` that transforms the permutation to the next permutation in the lexicographic order is `O(n)` in the worst case.

The number of permutations of `n` distinct elements is `n!`. The number of [permutations of multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_of_multisets) is `n!/(n1!*n2!*...*nk!)` where `ni` is the number of equal elements of type `i`.

We have two different cases:

1. Distinct numbers (set).

   `next_permutation` is often (if not always) implemented with `O(1)` amortized time when all elements are distinct. The latter means that `next_permutation` will have `O(1)` average time when calling many times consequently.

   In this scenario, the complexity of your `permutationSort` function is `O(n!)` in the worst-case scenario because of `n!` loop iterations with the amortized `O(1)` call of `next_permutation`.
2. Numbers with repetitions (multiset)

   In this case, `next_permutation` has no guaranteed `O(1)` amortized complexity, but the number of 'permutations of multiset' could be much less than `n!`. The upper bound of the `permutationSort` function complexity is `O(n!*n)` in the worst case. I suppose it can be reduced to `O(n!)` but don't know how to prove this fact.

Comment: The reference implementation of `std::next_permutation` is amortised constant time if the argument has no duplicated elements, in which case the total running time is O(n!). If the argument has O(n) duplicated elements, amortised constant time cannot be guaranteed, but the total number of permutations is less and the analysis is much more complex.

Comment: @rici, Yes, don't know how I overlooked this fact

Answer (score 2):

Your example *isn't* measuring anything about the workings of `std::next_permutation`. It is only measuring how many times you call it. You *do* have O(n!) *calls* to `std::next_permutation`.

You have to look at the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) to find the complexity of code that you don't have the source of. Alternatively you can construct a type that counts swaps and comparisons, to get an empirical measure of the complexity. That isn't an analysis, but it provides similar information.